# Google Ads Reporting into Salesforce...?

Tags: google-ads-api, adsense

I have a client looking to bring Google Ads data — Impressions, Clicks, CTR, CPC, Spend, Conversions, etc — into their Salesforce every month. This data would be pulled in once per month.

They also want to utilize tools they already subscribe to rather than paying for additional services, notably Make.com (formerly Integromat), but they also have a subscription to Dataloader.io (I'm less versed in that).

My initial thinking was to create specific reports in Google Ads to be run at a particular time each month that includes the desired data, then use the Reporting API to go into those reports to pull the data for the specified periods. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to tap into it via Make properly, or if Google makes it possible to do what I'm looking to do.

How would you suggest or recommend accomplishing what's required?